# Window Visibility Not applying

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml

The following code does not make the window I run invisible. What am I missing? Initially, my goal was to bind the visibility of the window to the Model View's WindowVisibility Boolean property but when that wouldn't work, I removed the conditional triggering and just assigned a style that set it to collapsed but it still doesn't work.

```
<Window x:Class="WindowWalker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1000" MinHeight="10" Height="85" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="Height">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <!--<Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowVisibility}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>-->
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="SettingsBrush" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_settings}"/>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="40" Margin="10" KeyUp="SearchBoxKeyUp"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="results" ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWindowResult}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ResultWindow.Title}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There is nothing like an invisible window. You may want to take a look at the WindowState and WindowStyle properties. Or write a console app, which doesn't have any window at all.

Comment: Its suppose to go invisible sometimes but I took out the conditional triggers for this question since even directly setting the styles was not working. If you look at the linked github blob, you will see the commented out portion of the XAML page that was suppose to trigger invisibility based on a Boolean.

Comment: Please don't expect people to follow links to other sites. If you have a specific problem with your code, post it to your question and explain what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Grabbed the blob and put it on here.